# How do you switch python 2 and 3 quickly?

Tags: python, windows-7

I need to use both python 2 and python 3.

The only way to change the default python used upon opening a .py file to is change the PATH environment variable. The steps are troublesome.

Can I have some windows batch script which modify the PATH variable for me?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been on Windows in a while. Does Windows have `python3` and `python2` as commands, or is it just `python`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)

Comment: @monkut This is not the same. I am asking if there is a way so that I can omit the long process which go through Computer -> Advance Setting -> Environment Variable

Comment: add them both to the PATH variable, and just rename the exe's python27.exe and python31.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, modify the PATH through a batch script:

This will start Python2:

```
C:\> set PATH=C:\Python27\;%PATH%
C:\> python.exe
```

This will start Python3:

```
C:\> set PATH=C:\Python32\;%PATH%
C:\> python.exe
```

*(Notice that the changed PATH is only valid for your current command shell session)*

Comment: And then you can even leave one command shell open for each of the interpreters you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regedit to export the path key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.

This way you create two reg files: one with python2 in the path and one with python3. Double clicking the respective file will change the path accordingly.

Comment: I followed this advice and now my setup was totally messed up. Command prompt start Python32 eventhough the PATH has Python27 in it(no Python32). IDLE started with Python27 no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I got a easy way to switch. Install both python27 and python33 in C:> . Then there will be two folders python27 and python33. Set the system path to python27 by default. If you want to use python33, change python27 folder name to something like python27_274 and change python33 folder name to python27:)