# Blender3D - Installing along side python 2.7 win7 64bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, blender

I'm interested in doing some work in Blender3D, but the latest release won't run and I believe it is because of my current python 2.7 install, which I use due to certain modules not supporting python 3.3.

When I run blender, I get a popup window error titled, "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" with the info:

```
Runtime Error!
Program C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information
```

I also get the following message in the console that pops up behind the main Blender UI:

```
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.69\python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
raise CodecRegistryError,\
                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I get around this while not destroying/removing my 2.7 install so I can continue to use modules unsupported in 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.6x does need Python 3.x, but there are a lot of folks switching between the two versions of Python because of the new software out there.

See: [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7) for a discussion of how this dual Python version setup and use has been done by others.

Alternatively, the documentation for Blender's older 2.4 version, found at: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/Python shows an example using Python 2.6.6, so if you're willing to forgo the features of Blender 2.69, that may be a possibility.

The Blender 2.5 documentation is no longer available on blender.org, but the version of the page preserved on archive.org warns that the 2.5 version of the Blender Python API is unstable.