# how to install and use more than one version of python at a time using windows

Tags: python, shared-libraries, multiple-versions

I'm just learning python and most of my scripts are therefore 3.3 at the moment.

However I would like to be able to write some scripts using python 2.7.

Particularly there is a Gmail script I would like to use

[Gmail Python Library](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail)

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to install 2.7 and 3.3. and switch between them when developing python?

Comment: Yes, of course it is; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3809314/3001761

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it can be done, I have installed 32 and 64 bit Pythons concurrently without problem (all less than version 3).  You won't be able to use the file associations for each, but you can start each Python and load thinks from within the interpreter.  The only place that you could run into problems is if the two versions have colliding registry keys.  I haven't seen this happen but different Python ports could handle this differently.

Best regards,
Marie