# Python dual install

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I set permanent paths for both Python 2 and 3 in command prompt such that I can invoke either every time I open the command window ie 'python2' for python 2 interpreter or 'python3' for python 3 interpreter

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: For windows 7:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7

Comment: @SimeonVisser Windows 7 ultimate

Comment: For ubuntu:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/196071/need-to-have-2-versions-of-python

just apt-get both versions

Comment: you haven’t  provided the operating system used so as to answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Just use [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows): `py -2` runs Python 2 and `py -3` runs Python 3.

If you add `#! python3` (shebang) at the top of your script then `py your_script.py` will use Python 3, if you add `#! python2` then it will use Python 2 automatically.

You can also [configure it to run all *.py files by default](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-file-associations).

Answer (score 0):

Create a python2.bat and a python3.bat file somewhere on your path (could in your main python folder). That file only contains the location of the relavant python.exe, e.g.

`C:\Programs\Python26\python.exe %*`