# How do I confirm my shebang line worked for python?

Tags: python, shebang

How do I confirm my shebang line worked for python? I'm on a windows machine.

My default python is python3.3 but I would like to use python2.7 for my current script.
How do I know if the shebang worked? This is my quick code to attempt to confirm

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7.6
import sys

print (sys.version)
```

However, I am being told that I'm still on python3.3. I know this is simple but I haven't found anything that can quickly answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shebang lines are a Unix-ism, not a Windows thing.  On Windows you will need to launch your script with the correct interpreter.  One idea would be to change the file extension to `.py2` and then associate that with the Python 2 interpreter.

You can also look at [PEP 397](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), which describes a new launcher in Python 3.3 which can locate other Python interpreter versions according to your shebang line.  This is a Python 3.3 feature, not a Windows one, just to be clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809404/3214255

Same thing just a bit more straight forward