# How to use python2.7.5 supported library in Python3.x?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.5, influxdb, influxdb-python

I want to use Python library to handle InfluxDb. But InfluxDb documentation says that they support only python `2.7.x` and i have only python `3.5.2` version installed in my setup.

I want to use python `2.7.5` with python `3.5.2` environment. I want to know if there is any way to do this kind of back-porting.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811713/is-it-ok-to-install-both-python-2-7-and-3-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to install both Python 2.7 and 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811713/is-it-ok-to-install-both-python-2-7-and-3-5)