# how to change template directory for scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, python-3.5

I have python 2.7 and 3.5 on my machine , and i want start a new project using python 2.7 as a base interpreter, but whenever i do `scrapy startproject <project name>` it shows python 3.5 as the template directory,

```
New Scrapy project 'startproject', using template directory 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\scrapy\\templates\\project'
```

so my question is how can i change template directories from 3.5 to 2.7,

any help?

Comment: use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/), so you can define which python version to use for each environment

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197237/5276801 to explain how to choose which interpreter  a python script is ran from

Comment: @eLRuLL i did , it uses 2.7 for virtualenv because used `virtualenv -p <path to 2.7>  <path to env>` but it doesn't work on scrapy

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling scrapy in virtualenv 
and then vc python