# How to install python 32bit alongside anaconda 64bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, environment-variables

I have `Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)` installed on windows 10. I then [downloaded and installed](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) `Python 2.7 | (32-bit)`.

My goal is to be able to open the command prompt and select either python 3.6 or 2.7 based on the environmental variable name.

Example:

```
python ---> Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)
python2 ---> Python 2.7 | (32-bit)
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7) and I implemented the answer suggesting to use conda to create an ad hoc environment. However this approach leads to python 64-bit instead of 32-bit.

Can you suggest me a nice way to set up the environmental variables without messing anything up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved my problem:

1. renamed `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe` to `python27.exe` and `pythonw27.exe` (give the name you want)
2. created [enviromental variable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWNhvq514Qs) by adding the path where `.exe` files are stored (ex: `C:\Python27\`)
3. Followed instructions of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpKJHUPTjmk) to install pip. Remember to change on top [this script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) `python` to whatever new environmental variable name you gave (ex: `#!/usr/bin/env python27`)

Note: no need to touch anaconda!

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to install them as normal then when you come to connect to one or the other just run python2 or python3 on the command line or am I missing the point of the question.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3l5pc9/using_python_3_and_python_2_on_the_same_machine/

Comment: when I open the command prompt I type python, I run python3.6 . I would like to be able to type something like python2 (or whatever else) to run python2.7.... however I don't know how to do that

Comment: so if you are running a python script in python2 you could say "python2 script.py" or if you are running it in python3 you could put "python3 script.py". when you install python these commands should be available by default even when both are installed.

Comment: if I type python2 and python3 I do not get anything but: 'python2/3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. That is my problem....

Comment: sorry i haven't used python for a few years I think the commands may be py -2.x or py -3.x (x being for the version)

Comment: I still get the same message:
'py2.7/py3.6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: sorry, i have just tested on a virtual machine its C:\Python27\Python.exe for python 2.7 and C:\Python36\Python.exe

Comment: yeah I think I figured it out... now the problem is pip which seems not to be working

Comment: I think my answer works fine... check it out if you are interesed