# Simulate keypress from a graphical change

Tags: python, keypress, capture, simulate

I'm just getting into coding, so everything is all very new and exciting for me, whilst equally confusing.

I've been pondering a scenario, described below, and wondered if it would be possible to make a program to do it, or if one already exists?

My research so far has pointed me towards a python program, but that might be incorrect in itself!

Imagine you are on a certain well-known video hosting site, watching a traffic light change colours, from green to red and back again. Exciting! Now, is there a way to have a background program monitor a certain section of screen, and simulate a keypress when the program identifies the light changing colour?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

This should all be possible using python, and if you are new python is a good language to start with. I have played with java, c/c++, python and others, but love python. I just did a quick google search of "monitor screen pixels python" and "simulate keypress python", and found:

example: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800458/quickly-getting-the-color-of-some-pixels-on-the-screen-in-python-on-windows-7)

example: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)