# how to sense if a character is touching a colour

Tags: python

i am making a game and i need to be able to sense if a character is touching a tree or not and i can't  because the tree is part of the background.

i've already tried using x and y co-ordinates but the trees aren't in a specific clump so this doesn't work. i also tried using a piece of code - look below - that detects if something is touching something else, however, the thing has to be defined and i can't define the tree.

```
def tree():
    tree = #brown

if sprite_x < 0 + sprite_width and sprite_x + tree_width > 0 and sprite_y < 0 + sprite_height and sprite_height + sprite_y > tree_height :
     #do stuff
```

i expect the code to sense if the character is touching a brown colour (the tree) and to allow me to use that output.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about how the trees are indicated?

Comment: the trees aren't indicated that's why i'm trying to get a code running purely on sensing the colour

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you can access the screen pixels the solution would be pretty straight forward, something like `if pixel_array[sprite_x, sprite_y] == BROWN` where `pixel_array` is the screen pixels and `BROWN` some variable pointing to the same color used for the trees

Comment: that would work @rotemtal but how would i access the screen pixels?

Comment: Well, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800458/quickly-getting-the-color-of-some-pixels-on-the-screen-in-python-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks @rotemtal that has really helped answer my question!