# why win32gui's getpixel() is lot slower in windows 10 compared to windows 7 ? is there any solution?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, pywin32, getpixel

I know that using win32gui is the fastest way to get the pixel data compared to PIL and other such libraries. Up until now I was executing my code in windows 7 laptop(old) where it was working very fast but recently I bought a new laptop(processor is superior to my older one) which came with Windows 10 inbuilt but in windows 10 the same program is a lot slower and after having a closer look I understood that the getpixel part of code is making the entire program slow. so to be sure I calculated the time taken for the same code to execute in both windows 10 & windows 7 and what I found is the same code took just 0.03 seconds in windows 7 whereas it took 17 seconds in windows 10(even after having higher processing power). Is there any solution for this? is there any separate library for windows 10 which is faster?

```
from win32 import win32gui
import time

a = []


def getList():
    temp = []

    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, 100,100)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    px_tuple=((i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff))
    temp.append(px_tuple)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(i_desktop_window_id, i_desktop_window_dc)    
    return temp

start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(1000):
    a= getList()
stop = time.perf_counter()
print(stop - start)
```

Comment: There are several possible solutions (disable desktop composition, get multiple pixels at once), all of them are documented in the linked question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly getting the color of some pixels on the screen in Python on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800458/quickly-getting-the-color-of-some-pixels-on-the-screen-in-python-on-windows-7)