# pyautogui.pixel works perfectly for a while, and then randomly stops working and gives errors

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyautogui

I have been implementing pyautogui.pixel in many forms of code, I will get a normal desirable output for a random short while, and at some point, the function will stop working, and I will get error messages.

**Simple example code:**

```
while True:
    print(pyautogui.pixel(1766, 1539))
```

**Output:**

```
(30, 30, 30)
```

**The eventual error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zyoli\Desktop\scrap_bot\gathering.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(pyautogui.pixel(1766, 1539))
  File "C:\Users\zyoli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 584, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\zyoli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\zyoli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are switching some windows/app while running the code. Maybe because of the animation(while opening a new window), Pyautogui raises an error. `get_pixel` from the screen is slow. Maybe this thread can help you:
[Quickly getting the color of some pixels on the screen in Python on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800458/quickly-getting-the-color-of-some-pixels-on-the-screen-in-python-on-windows-7)