# check if the monitor is connected

Tags: c#, status, monitor

I've to make a simple program that reports to a server the state of the monitor (is it on/off or simply if it's not connected).
So far I'm using this method I found on another discussion, but it simply returns to me true every times, even if I've disconnected my monitor.

```
public static Boolean isMonitorActive() 
        {
            Boolean active = false;
            var query = "select * from WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams";
            using (var wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", query))
            {
                var results = wmiSearcher.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in results)
                {
                    // get the "Active" property and cast to a boolean, which should 
                    // tell us if the display is active. I've interpreted this to mean "on"
                    active = (Boolean)wmiObj["Active"];
                    return active;
                }
            }
            return active;
        }
```

I've to check the status of the monitor every 2-3 minutes, so I need to use something different from the MonitorCout variable in System, because it's initialized and remain the same from the beginning to end of the program (If I'm not mistaken).
Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: A `timer` would help with the constant checks.

Comment: Here's a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020559/screen-allscreen-is-not-giving-the-correct-monitor-count

Comment: In .Net you can check for monitors with the Screen.AllScreens collection. I think the not connected state is hard to retreive as a not connected monitor is actually not there in windows and therefore is not listed somewhere (try it out in controlpanel display settings)

Comment: @wonko79 The `AllScreens` is statically initialised once only in the program so it won't change afterwards if the user disconnects a monitor. This is addressed in the answer in the link I gave.

Comment: @MatthewWatson as I was saying in the question, I can't use AllScreens because I've to check when the monitor disconnects during the program execution.

Comment: @user2190639 Yes but look at [the link I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020559/screen-allscreen-is-not-giving-the-correct-monitor-count) - it gives a solution which uses the Windows API `EnumDisplayMonitors()` function.

Comment: oh thanks! I've missed that part. Anyway, I don't know if the problem is because I'm on a laptop, but when I test by connecting an external monitor and I unplug it I always get monCount = 1. The code seems to work tough, because when I use 2 monitor monCount = 2