# Incorrect dpi returned by WMI class multi displays (Win32_DesktopMonitor)

Tags: c#, wmi

I have two displays, set to different dpi settings: `120` and `240` (125% and 250% in windows). I'm trying to obtain those settings in c# as follows:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");

foreach (ManagementObject monitor in managementObjectSearcher.Get())
{
    dpi = (uint) monitor["PixelsPerXLogicalInch"];
    Console.Write(dpi);
}
```

This snippet returns `120` twice. Why is not returning the correct values?

Btw `app.manifest` includes:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
     <windowsSettings>
         <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">permonitorv2,permonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DPI scale for all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438430/how-to-get-dpi-scale-for-all-screens)

Comment: It's not a WPF app. Seems dirty solution at first view.

Comment: Microsoft is very worried about breaking apps that already handle the notification themselves.  More config is required to convince the OS and Winforms that you want the automagic, details [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms).  Not so sure if WMI got the same appcompat treatment.