# I want to get the scale of all displays C#

Tags: c#, dpi

I have tried the following answers., but all the results of the main display are returned.
(I have specified "Effective"...)
[How to get DPI scale for all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438430/how-to-get-dpi-scale-for-all-screens)

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know.
I welcome any help.

Comment: You need to enumerate your monitors with something like `EnumDisplayMonitors`.

Comment: I'm using "System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens" and it doesn't work.
How should I use "EnumDisplayMonitors"?

Comment: Use your brain, type 'monitor' in the search filter in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow and you'll see all monitor-related functions. You need to enumerate the monitors you have, then pass it to the function in the question above. You will need to convert some of the handles, find the functions for that where I've referred you to.