# Windows Screens.AllScreens does not update after switching the main display

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Windows Screens.AllScreens does not update after switching the main display.

I am trying to manipulate a multi-monitor setup with a instrument that has a small screen (800/480) and an external monitor (1920/1080). The external monitor must always be the primary screen. I need to do certain tasks on the small monitor like changing the orientation (DMDO_180/DMDO_DEFAULT). and triggering a touch screen calibration (tabcal.exe). Both of the operations require that the screen that the operations are being executed on be the primary display.

I have the code to change the display but when the screens changed it is not reflected in Screen.AllScreens. When AllScreen is not updated my tasks fail because the primary screen is not correct.

I have noticed that the Screen object does get updated on a context switch but I need to force it to happen. I have looked at [Screen.AllScreen is not giving the correct monitor count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020559/screen-allscreen-is-not-giving-the-correct-monitor-count). It mentions that "***I had a look at the source (remember we can do that using the MS Symbol servers). AllScreens uses an unmanaged API to get the screens on the first access, then stores the result in a static variable for later use.
The consequence of this, is that if the number of monitors changes while your program is running; then Screen.AllScreens will not pick up the change.***" This is not completely correct. I have hooked the window loaded event and If I set a breakpoint before it is triggered and change the primary screen, when the event is triggered that AllScreens object gets updated and shows the correct primary screen.

An example of what I have done to try and mimic this behavior is to trigger events between my application code and the code I found on the internet that uses the DEVMODE struct to manipulate the displays but triggering event between the two does not update the AllSCreens object.

The code to do this is thousands of line so I will post on request.

I am using VS2015, C#, WPF.

How do I force AllScreens to update using the unmanaged API?

Comment: "Switching" is very vague.  Just try it, subscribe the SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging event.  If it doesn't fire when you "switch" then you indeed won't get a different AllScreens property value.  If this is something hacky then you must send the WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message yourself.

Comment: I have added to my main window:

Comment: Thank you this works.I execute PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); and wait for WM_DISPLAYCHANGE in IntPtr hwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) to signal my semaphore.

Comment: It is sent message, that makes using SendMessageTimeout() instead of PostMessage() appropriate.

Comment: I stumbled across this today, did you manage to get an update of the screen objects? I did send the broadcast, but in my case the screen objects will not change: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77774880/356726

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged seems to get fired on Main display switch.