# Is there a way to refresh/update the Screen object in a Win Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Is there a way to update the `Screen` object? Remark: Screen object like in `(Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)`

The object does not change if the scaling or other properties are changed. A very detailed analysis is to be found here: [Windows Screens.AllScreens does not update after switching the main display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46592358/356726)

In the comments it looked like sending a broadcast `PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)` would cause an update of the screen object.

I have tried that, but my screen objects do not update. Is there a way to force an update?

The trouble is the caching static field not being "nulled" correctly in all situations.

```
public unsafe static Screen[] AllScreens
{
  get
      {
        if (s_screens is null)
           {
              if (s_multiMonitorSupport)
```

Actually sending the request should null the cache

```
private static void OnDisplaySettingsChanging(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Now that we've responded to this event, we don't need it again until
    // someone re-queries. We will re-add the event at that time.
    SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging -= new EventHandler(OnDisplaySettingsChanging);

    // Display settings changed, so the set of screens we have is invalid.
    s_screens = null;
}
```

Comment: Use reflection to call `private static void OnDisplaySettingsChanging`? (src https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/c6a465de8b7a6386914eb9936c12f2949192175b/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Screen.cs#L125) Hmmm, this reference to `WM_REFLECT` is a bit weird https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/21b4a8585362c1bc12d545b63e62a0d9dd4e8673/src/libraries/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents/src/Microsoft/Win32/SystemEvents.cs#L1213

Comment: Maybe you need to listen for extra events? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762140/what-is-the-notification-when-the-number-of-monitors-changes

Comment: Great idea using REFLECTION, it is even easier. I can simply `null` the "caching" `s_screens` static property and all screen objects are re-created! Thanks! It is working. I totally missed the idea with the reflection hack! Use saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: I'd recommend calling `OnDisplaySettingsChanging` to ensure the event handler is removed the same number of times that it is added.

Comment: Sending WM_DISPLAYCHANGE should reset screens, can you test this https://pastebin.com/raw/4DBXthUS if it doesn't work it may partly explain the original issue

Comment: I can confirm your snippet works, also I can confirm `OnDisplaySettingsChanging` is called. Nevertheless the whole thing acts strange. For instance at my place a breakpoint at `if (s_multiMonitorSupport)` is only hit once. After sending the Broadcast I would expect it to be called a 2nd time.

While my solution with Reflection gives me the updated data, the solution with broadcast does not. My solution still has the issue, that the event is then subscribed multiple times.

Btw, thanks for the help and effort.

Comment: As Hans P. also pointed out to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeouta I will also try this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of several people (comments) I have a (currently) working solution.

What works best for me is to call the private(!) callback method of `Screen`, which is invoked when the `SettingsChanging` event occurs. `SettingsChanging` ONLY is insufficient as other changes (e.g. Scaling) pass unnoticed.

Needless to say that kind of solution is a hack.

```
MethodInfo? method = typeof(Screen).GetMethod("OnDisplaySettingsChanging", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Debug.Assert(method != null, "Method OnDisplaySettingsChanging not found");
method.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] { "dummy object", EventArgs.Empty });
```

Sending the broadcast of `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` also works, but less reliable for me. It is asynchronous and I have to wait until the change occurred first. Also I force a lot of Screen objects in other applications to update as well (side effects ???).

Due to the nature of the broadcast it is also impossible to determine in my application's `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` handling if the change is caused "by me" or external reasons.

Simon Mourier's complete example is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/4DBXthUS

In the other question [Windows Screens.AllScreens does not update after switching the main display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46592358/356726) it also has a comment, so if going with

```
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

it is probably better to use `SendMessageTimeout()`

> It is sent message, that makes using `SendMessageTimeout()` instead of `PostMessage()` appropriate. – *Hans Passant*

Thanks again for all the help.

---

SM code snippet in case the pastebin expires:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }
    }

    public partial class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("DisplaySettingsChanged");
            var button = new Button { Text = "Click me" };
            button.Click += (s, e) => PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Controls.Add(button);
        }

        private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new(0xFFFF);
        private const int WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 126;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    }
}
```