# Bring window to top

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to bring my Form to the top, take screenshot, save it and then minimize it back using the following code.

```
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.TopMost = true;

            Application.DoEvents();

            string keys = "%" + "{PrtSc}";
            SendKeys.SendWait(keys);
            Clipboard.GetImage().Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.TopMost = false;
```

I thought the code will always bring the window on top and take the screenshot. However I noticed that its not 100% working:
The machine is too slow, so when the code that bring the window to top executes, the entire window does not appear.
Sometimes It does not bring it to top, so the pic contains some user activity.

How can I bring it completely to the top and wait till its done complete and then take a screenshot and reverse it.

Please note that there is a single form in the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/how-may-i-capture-the-screen-in-a-bitmap

Comment: When you open the Form you could use formname.ShowDialog();, It will be topmost then

Comment: Any specific reason for down votes or just for fun ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a timer. run the first part of the code(up until and including:"Application.DoEvents();"), and start the timer. On the tick code check the "this.TopMost" status and only if it is the topmost form take the screen shot and stop the timer.