# VB.NET - Take a screenshot of all screens on a computer

Tags: vb.net, screenshot

I'm trying to capture any and all screens on a computer, I tried to fiddle with `Screen.AllScreens` and also something with `VirtualScreens` that I can't remember, so I moved to `PrimaryScreen` to make sure everything else worked properly.

Here is my current class:

```
Public Class wmCapture

    Public Shared Function screenCapture()
        Dim userName As String = Environment.UserName
        Dim savePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        Dim dateString As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        Dim captureSavePath As String = String.Format("{0}\WM\{1}\capture_{2}.png", savePath, userName, dateString)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap( _
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, _
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

        Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        gfx.CopyFromScreen( _
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location, _
            New Point(0, 0), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size)

        bmp.Save(captureSavePath)

    End Function

End Class
```

What should I be using in the Screen namespace to include all active screens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. I made a couple adjustments and can confirm it's working on my end.

```
Public Shared Sub screenCapture()
    Dim userName As String = Environment.UserName
    Dim savePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    Dim dateString As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    Dim captureSavePath As String = String.Format("{0}\WM\{1}\capture_{2}.png", savePath, userName, dateString)
    ' This line is modified for multiple screens, also takes into account different screen size (if any)
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap( _
                        Screen.AllScreens.Sum(Function(s As Screen) s.Bounds.Width),
                        Screen.AllScreens.Max(Function(s As Screen) s.Bounds.Height))
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    ' This line is modified to take everything based on the size of the bitmap
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                       SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                       0, 0, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size)
    ' Oh, create the directory if it doesn't exist
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(captureSavePath))
    bmp.Save(captureSavePath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dan, so I should be using a Sub instead of a function? I reference the function and class in my main.vb (form1)

Comment: Also I have a directory check within a different class as part of my application "load" events, but thanks for adding yours :)

Comment: Unless the method has a return type, use a `Sub`. In your case, the method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you again for your help. - But as you can see my second screen is blank yet there's a space for it. - For example I have netflix opened on my second monitor. - Note my main monitor is on the right and my 2nd on the left. http://i.imgur.com/LGq6Iuo.png

Comment: How about without netflix?

Comment: OK I see your problem once I moved my monitors around. It's not working with the primary display to the right of the secondary

Comment: Another edit, working with displays in goofy locations i.e. your pc :)

Comment: @DanVerdolino  What about if I needed just the active screen where the cursor is present?>

Answer (score 0):

```
Clipboard.Clear()
SendKeys.SendWait("^{PRTSC}")

While Not Clipboard.ContainsImage()
    Thread.Sleep(500)
End While
Dim Screenshot As Image = Clipboard.GetImage()
Return Screenshot
```

Check this out
[Multi-Monitor Screen-Shot by Smitty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/capture-the-screen-into-a-bitmap/78209847#78209847)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good practice to include an explanation with your code to help readers understand how the code works and ultimately answers the question.