# How to Calculate the Windows Screen Scaling a User has set with c#

Tags: c#, dpi

For an application which will be used to calibrate optical systems, I need to know the scaling a user has set in his/her settings... I have tried to get the DPI values for the physical screen and the virtual screen (with applied user scaling). By dividing I should get the scaling factor... but I haven't managed to get it to work.

So is there a way to get the scaling factor right away through a DLL or something else? Or was my way correct and I have to calculate it? If so: how can I get the two values for physical screen and the virtual screen (with applied user scaling)?

I have tried to Use the "user32.dll", the "Shcore.dll", `Control.AutoScaleFactor` and the `System.Drawing`... In any way I only get the values for the virtual screen (with applied user scaling) or a relationship of 1 which would mean the user has set its scaling to 100% which isn't true. I did not manage to get the physical screen DPI or a correct scaling factor

Here's what I have tried by using the `GetDpiForMonitor` function

```
{
 [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDpiForMonitor(IntPtr hmonitor, MonitorDpiType dpiType, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY);

    private enum MonitorDpiType
    {
        EffectiveDpi = 0,
        AngularDpi = 1,
        RawDpi = 2,
    }

    private void ShowPPI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr primaryMonitor = IntPtr.Zero; 
        uint dpiX, dpiY;
        int result = GetDpiForMonitor(primaryMonitor, MonitorDpiType.EffectiveDpi, out dpiX, out dpiY);


        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can calculate it from the results of GetMonitorInfo and GetDpiForMonitor.

Comment: sadly thats not very helpfull. I tried it in many ways and writting "GetMonitorInfo and GetDpiForMonitor "  does not help.  so how can i implement them and how do i get the pure monitor DPI??  i only get the user scaled one, with 135% thats 130 instead of 96 as a example

Comment: Show what you tried so far. Then other people can suggest a modification.

Comment: of course! i guess i should have included that in the first place.

Comment: You are supposed to include the code itself in the question. Then, have you tried [GetDpiForMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor)? If so, what is the issue with it?

Comment: My issue is that i cant get sensful results, but to be honest i dont realy know how to use the funktion. when i use the variable result it displays a huge value like -21309

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get scaling factor for each monitor, e.g. 1, 1.25, 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872044/how-to-get-scaling-factor-for-each-monitor-e-g-1-1-25-1-5)

Comment: i havent got much tie for now... thats why i cant properly code and test, but it seems very promisin so i will look in to it when i have more free time!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the monitor handle of primary monitor by MonitorFromWindow or other fuctions.

So if you want to get the primary monitor's DPI Scale, the code will be like the following.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class DpiHelper
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(
        IntPtr hwnd,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);

    enum MONITOR_DEFAULTTO : uint
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002,
    }

    [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
    static extern int GetDpiForMonitor(
        IntPtr hmonitor,
        MONITOR_DPI_TYPE dpiType,
        out uint dpiX,
        out uint dpiY);

    enum MONITOR_DPI_TYPE
    {
        MDT_Effective_DPI = 0,
        MDT_Angular_DPI = 1,
        MDT_Raw_DPI = 2,
        MDT_Default = MDT_Effective_DPI
    }

    const double DefaultPixelsPerInch = 96D;

    public static void CheckPrimaryMonitorDpi()
    {
        var monitorHandle = MonitorFromWindow(
            IntPtr.Zero,
            MONITOR_DEFAULTTO.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

        var result = GetDpiForMonitor(
            monitorHandle,
            MONITOR_DPI_TYPE.MDT_Default,
            out uint dpiX,
            out uint dpiY);
        if (result is 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"DPI Scale X {dpiX / DefaultPixelsPerInch}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"DPI Scale Y {dpiY / DefaultPixelsPerInch}");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add a correct application manifest. [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)