# Fullscreen WPF window on a MS Windows system with multiple Monitors and different DPI settings

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, dpi, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 11 system with 2 monitors:

- One 4k monitor with scale factor of 150% and
- One FullHD monitor on scale factor 100% (Of course this needs to work with differnt system settings too)

I want to show a new WPF Window on the other monitor - meaning on the monitor my main app is currently not being displayed on. So if my main window is on the 4k monitor then I want to show the new window on the FullHD monitor.

The new windows should be showing a fullscreen view of my webcam. But having different DPI settings makes it hard to show a fullscreen window in the correct position and size.

My Window XAML is straight forward and looks like this

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyApp.Fullscreen"
    x:ClassModifier="internal"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    AllowsTransparency="False"
    Background="Black"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    Topmost="True"
    WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="WebCam" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I initialize it like this

```
 var allSystemScreens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
 var otherScreen = DetermineOtherScreen(allSystemScreens);

 var window = new Fullscreen();
 window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

 window.Left = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
 window.Top = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
 window.Width = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
 window.Height = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

 window.Show();
```

But it does not work. It does not show the window fully on the monitor or is way bigger than the monitor and is reaching into the second one.

I played around with the values from the WorkingArea. But it never works.

[My app is DPI per-monitor-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537991/575376). I tried to apply the [scale factor that I read from the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187663/c-sharp-how-to-get-real-screen-resolution-in-multiple-monitors-context) but no matter what values I use - it is never correct positioned or sized.

How to do it correctly? Or is there an easier or better way to achieve this? Maybe without using the `WindowStartupLocation.Manual`.

Comment: It is hard to use those Window's properties reliably under Per-Monitor DPI setting because they are affected by DPI of each monitor. Instead, I recommend to use GetWindowPlacement and SetWindowPlacement Win32 functions. In addition, you need to take into account the gap by extended frame bounds depending on Window's WindowStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so instead of using the `WorkingArea` property, which may not take into account the DPI scaling, we can use the `Bounds` property of the monitor to calculate the correct position and size, in my new suggestion, I'm using the `Bounds` property of the monitor, which represents the entire monitor area, including any taskbars or other system elements and by dividing the `Bounds` values by the DPI scale factor, I can ensure that the position and size are calculated correctly for the specific monitor's DPI scaling!

Additionally, I've added `window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;` to set the window to fullscreen mode.

```
var otherScreen = DetermineOtherScreen(allSystemScreens);

var otherScreenScaleFactor = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(window);
double otherScreenScale = otherScreenScaleFactor.DpiScaleX;

double left = otherScreen.Bounds.Left / otherScreenScale;
double top = otherScreen.Bounds.Top / otherScreenScale;
double width = otherScreen.Bounds.Width / otherScreenScale;
double height = otherScreen.Bounds.Height / otherScreenScale;
    
window.Left = left;
window.Top = top;
window.Width = width;
window.Height = height;

window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it does not work. The window is not Fullscreen and not correct positioned.

Comment: @juergend plz check my answer again.

Comment: Amazing. This seems to work. Important is that I call `window.Show()` before I call your code. It does not work when I call it afterwards. I do some checking and get back to this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Due to `WindowState.Maximized` it looks correct sized to fullscreen. If you change that to `WindowState.Normal` then you see that it is not 100% correctly sized. If I remove the lines `width /= scaleFactor;  height /= scaleFactor;` then it is also sized correctly.

Comment: You don't need to multiply it. The 2 lines I removed just resized a second time which was wrong. `double width = otherScreen.Bounds.Width / otherScreenScale;` already takes the scale factor into account. If you do `width /= scaleFactor;` then it is scaled a second time.

Comment: I can edit it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate Left, Top, Width and Height of Window but as I commented, such calculation can be screwed up depending on the number of screens and their placement. Instead, I recommend to use Win32 functions that are not affected by DPI of each monitor. In addition, if WindowStyle of Window is not WindowStyle.None, you will need to take into account thickness of extended frame bounds which is known to be 7 when DPI is 96.

**EDIT:**

I identified the cause of incorrect size of window after this method is applied. If dpiAwareness is specifiled in the application manifest, the size will not correctly set in the case of newly created window. The version of .NET Framework or .NET does not matter.

The workaround is pretty simple. Just call this method again at Loaded event. I modified the code and it should work when dpiAwareness is specified.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static void SetWindowRect(Window window, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect)
    {
        SetWindowRect(window, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }

    public static void SetWindowRect(Window window, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
        GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement);

        int left = x;
        int top = y;
        int right = x + width;
        int bottom = y + height;

        if (window.WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
        {
            IntPtr monitorHandle = MonitorFromPoint(new POINT(x, y), MONITOR_DEFAULTTO.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);
            if (monitorHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (TryGetMonitorDpi(monitorHandle, out DpiScale dpi))
                {
                    const double DefaultExtendedFrameBoundsThickness = 7D;
                    int extendedFrameBoundsThickness = (int)(DefaultExtendedFrameBoundsThickness * dpi.PixelsPerDip);

                    left -= extendedFrameBoundsThickness;
                    right += extendedFrameBoundsThickness;
                    bottom += extendedFrameBoundsThickness;
                }
            }
        }

        windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition = new RECT(left, top, right, bottom);
        SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref windowPlacement);
    }

    private static bool TryGetMonitorDpi(IntPtr monitorHandle, out DpiScale dpi)
    {
        const double DefaultPixelsPerInch = 96D;

        if (GetDpiForMonitor(monitorHandle, MONITOR_DPI_TYPE.MDT_Default, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY) == S_OK)
        {
            dpi = new DpiScale(dpiX / DefaultPixelsPerInch, dpiY / DefaultPixelsPerInch);
            return true;
        }
        dpi = default;
        return false;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public uint length;
        public uint flags;
        public uint showCmd;
        public POINT ptMinPosition;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public RECT rcNormalPosition;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.top = top;
            this.right = right;
            this.bottom = bottom;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(
        POINT pt,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);

    private enum MONITOR_DEFAULTTO : uint
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002,
    }

    [DllImport("Shcore.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetDpiForMonitor(
        IntPtr hmonitor,
        MONITOR_DPI_TYPE dpiType,
        out uint dpiX,
        out uint dpiY);

    private enum MONITOR_DPI_TYPE
    {
        MDT_Effective_DPI = 0,
        MDT_Angular_DPI = 1,
        MDT_Raw_DPI = 2,
        MDT_Default = MDT_Effective_DPI
    }

    private const int S_OK = 0x0;
}
```

Then you can use this method like the following.

```cs
var window = new Fullscreen();
WindowHelper.SetWindowRect(window, otherScreen.WorkingArea); // 1st call
window.Loaded += OnLoaded;
window.Show();

void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
    WindowHelper.SetWindowRect(window, otherScreen.WorkingArea); // 2nd call
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Interesting - this works if my current window (not the fullscreen window) is on the monitor that I want to show the fullscreen view. If not then it does not fullscreen and not position correctly. I have a small window where my webcam feed is displayed. When I double click it I want to show the fullscreen window with my webcam feed on the other monitor. And when the small window is on the same monitor as the fullscreen window then it works.

Comment: This method will show a window exactly at a specified coordinates and size. Since you have not shown the code of your DetermineOtherScreen, I cannot reproduce.

Comment: My `DetermineOtherScreen()` method is currently hardcoded: `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[x]`  and I switch the index for each test run.

Comment: I see. I rechecked and found that if the app is on .NET Framework 4.8 or the window is already shown, this method works as expected but on .NET 7.0  and the window is newly created, its size may not be what is expected. In the latter case, after the window is loaded, you can make the window maximized. However, since WindowStyle is WindowStyle.None, the window may hide the taskbar of the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The code from the other answer works. So I go with this one.

Comment: I found the workaround and so modified the answer.