# Querying Windows display scaling

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to query the `Windows` display scaling setting programmatically:
[image]
In this case, I want it to return `125` since I configured my display to be at `125%` scaling. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dpi-related-apis-and-registry-settings#scale) article, the following `Windows API C++` code can be used:

```
// Get desktop dc
desktopDc = GetDC(NULL);
// Get native resolution
horizontalDPI = GetDeviceCaps(desktopDc,LOGPIXELSX);
verticalDPI = GetDeviceCaps(desktopDc,LOGPIXELSY);
```

However, this code always return `96` and `96` for the horizontal as well as vertical `DPI` which translates to `100%` scaling (according to the provided table):
[image]

This output is wrong since I still get the same result with `125%` scaling. How can it be done? I'm programming in `Java` so I can execute `C++` using [`JNA`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). `Windows API` solutions are preferred but everything else like a `.bat` script or `registry` query is also fine as long as it's reliable for all `Windows` versions from `7` to `10`.

Comment: Note that `LOGPIXELSY` will always return 96 for compatibility unless you have your app flagged as dpi-aware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864741/3764804) answer solved it:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    auto activeWindow = GetActiveWindow();
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(activeWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

    // Get the logical width and height of the monitor
    MONITORINFOEX monitorInfoEx;
    monitorInfoEx.cbSize = sizeof(monitorInfoEx);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &monitorInfoEx);
    auto cxLogical = monitorInfoEx.rcMonitor.right - monitorInfoEx.rcMonitor.left;
    auto cyLogical = monitorInfoEx.rcMonitor.bottom - monitorInfoEx.rcMonitor.top;

    // Get the physical width and height of the monitor
    DEVMODE devMode;
    devMode.dmSize = sizeof(devMode);
    devMode.dmDriverExtra = 0;
    EnumDisplaySettings(monitorInfoEx.szDevice, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode);
    auto cxPhysical = devMode.dmPelsWidth;
    auto cyPhysical = devMode.dmPelsHeight;

    // Calculate the scaling factor
    auto horizontalScale = ((double) cxPhysical / (double) cxLogical);
    auto verticalScale = ((double) cyPhysical / (double) cyLogical);

    std::cout << "Horizonzal scaling: " << horizontalScale << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vertical scaling: " << verticalScale;
}
```

Comment: There is something counterintuitive: when I call `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);` first in main, it reports a factor 1.0 for all monitors. If I don't, the factors match those of each monitor as shown in the control panel.