# WinForms Control.PointToScreen and high-resolution screen

Tags: .net, winforms, coordinates, screen, highdpi

I draw a so-called reversible line in a .NET Framework WinForms app using code like this:

```cs
ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(
    PointToScreen(new Point(x, y1)),
    PointToScreen(new Point(x, y2)),
    Color.Black);
```

If [high-dpi support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) is not turned on in the app and the app is launched on a hi-res screen, the `x`, `y1` and `y2` coordinates come from the mouse events as if the app worked on a 96 dpi screen because of the Windows dpi virtualization. But when I pass these numbers to the [Control.PointToScreen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen) function, it processes them taking into account the real resolution of the screen. As a result, the points I get from `PointToScreen` are shifted to the left-top corner on the screen on 4K screens.

Is there a simple way to overcome this problem? Please, take into account modern multi-monitor configurations in which every monitor may have its own resolution.

Comment: Make your app DpiAware.

Comment: @Jimi, this construction must work in both environments - when dpi awareness is on or off.

Comment: What *environments*? It's your app that declares itself DpiAware. When you do that, then you receive non-virtualized measures. When you don't, you may receive virtualized and non-virtualized measures, depending on what method/property you call/access. Not a difficult choice to make...

Comment: @Jimi, actually it is a control used on WinForms forms by others. So I can't control whether the surrounding 'environment' (app) is dpi-aware or not.

Comment: Start from here: [Detect if non DPI-aware application has been scaled/virtualized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864741/7444103). This may also help: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103). Take a look at the Mixed-Mode DPI Scaling and DPI and Device-Independent Pixels info. Also, note that you don't actually need `DrawReversibleLine`, you can draw directly to the Screen. And/or handle yourself [MapWindowPoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints) (the function `PointToScreen()` calls)