# issue with getting screenshot from clipboard (Visual Studio, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, screenshot

I have these lines of code that takes a screenshot and "gets" it:

```
    SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}");
    Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
    initScreenShot = new Bitmap(img);
```

But some times i get the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll

on the line`initScreenShot = new Bitmap(img);`, this happens about 25% of the times i run the code. Why is that?

Comment: you should try this approach, even better it doesn't mess up with user's clipboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/capture-the-screen-into-a-bitmap