# What's a faster way of getting a pixel's color from a secondary monitor?

Tags: c#

So I tried using

```
bmp.GetPixel(-100, 100);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-getpixel

But apparently I can't use a negative integer for it, throws out an error. So I then used

```
GetPixel(-100, 100);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel

And that worked but it's super slow...

Does anyone have a better method to get a pixel's color on a secondary monitor where I need to use a negative number for it's coordinate? I have spent hours trying to figure this out and any help or different methods would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry should have included the code for the screenshot, here it is.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(-1920, 0, 0, 1080, bmp.Size);
```

I just want to take a screenshot of the second monitor and save it in a bitmap so that I can search for the pixel faster.

Comment: You could save the monitor's display to a `Bitmap` and then use `.GetPixel()` on that `Bitmap`.

Comment: [Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.7.2) might be faster.

Comment: Tau that's what I tried doing but when I specified the negative coordinate for bmp.GetPixel(-100, 100) where bmp is my saved monitor display, it throws out an exception saying that it has to be a positive integer. 

Johnny Mopp, I couldn't get that to work either.

Damien, I added links to it to hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to get the bitmap from the screen? Yes the screen coordinates will be -100,100 but the Bitmap will always be relative to 0,0. So once you copy it to the bitmap it is offset from 0,0.

Comment: I should've been more specific with my comment.  I'm still saying that you could save the display into a `Bitmap` object, but then use relative positive coordinates (`x` being the screen's width - `100`, `y` not changing).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ah alright, I don't use stackoverflow often so I didn't know, thanks.

Comment: @JeffR. Added the code Jeff.

Comment: @Tau Also how would that work when the pixel is on the second monitor where every X coordinate is negative?

Comment: @ArcticWolf_11 if you [store an image of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363008/8420233) and then save that to a `Bitmap`, then all of the coordinates will be positive.

Comment: @Tau Ah alright, i'll give that a try, thanks!